# Include in a file wrong direction

Tags: php, include

When i include a file in like 1/2/3/file.php and in the file i do `<?php include ('../file2.php'); ?>` it sends me to : `1/2/3/../file2.php`

it should just send me to `../file2.php`. It seems like it does not use the ../ . Also the file does exist.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Jeremy Added a little thing it is hard to explain a small question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `__DIR__`

`<?php include (__DIR__.'../file2.php'); ?`>